# Help me to merge two queries

Tags: oracle

I have two queries in sql.
First query is:

```
select hotel_id , count(*) as NumberOfRooms
    from room
    group by hotel_id;
```

The result is:

```
# | hotel_id | NumberOfRooms
-----------------------------
1 | 1111     |            1
2 | 2222     |            2
3 | 3333     |            2
4 | 4444     |            1
```

Second query is:

```
select count(distinct client_id) as NumberOfClients
    from payment;
```

The result is:

```
# | NumberOfClients
--------------------
1 |            4
2 |            2
3 |            3
4 |            4
```

What I need looks something like this:

```
   # | hotel_id | NumberOfRooms   |NumberOfClients |
    -----------------------------------------------
    1 | 1111     |            1  |              4 |
    2 | 2222     |            2  |              2 |
    3 | 3333     |            2  |              3 |
    4 | 4444     |            1  |              4 |
```

And relationship model looks like this: [image]

The task itself was to  show for each hotel number of rooms in hotel and number of distinct clients that have been in hotel.

They both work fine, but because they are for two different tables I don't know how to properly join them into single query.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Here are table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE "RIADORA"."PAYMENT" 
   (    "CLIENT_ID" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PAYMENT_ID" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROOM_ID" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PAYMENT_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERIOD" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUMM" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSONAL_ID" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PAYMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PAYMENT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CLIENTP" FOREIGN KEY ("CLIENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "RIADORA"."CLIENT" ("CLIENT_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROOMP" FOREIGN KEY ("ROOM_ID")
      REFERENCES "RIADORA"."ROOM" ("ROOM_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PERSONALP" FOREIGN KEY ("PERSONAL_ID")
      REFERENCES "RIADORA"."PERSONAL" ("PERSONAL_ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."CLIENT_ID" IS 'ID number of client';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."PAYMENT_ID" IS 'ID number of payment';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."ROOM_ID" IS 'ID number of room';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."PAYMENT_DATE" IS 'Date when payment occured';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."PERIOD" IS 'Period of days, during which client stays at hotel';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."SUMM" IS 'Amount of money paid';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"."PERSONAL_ID" IS 'ID number of personal';
   COMMENT ON TABLE "RIADORA"."PAYMENT"  IS 'Payment data';
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "RIADORA"."ROOM" 
   (    "PRICE" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROOM_SIZE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROOM_ID" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "HOTEL_ID" NUMBER(20,6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROOM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ROOM_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "HOTEL_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("HOTEL_ID")
      REFERENCES "RIADORA"."HOTEL" ("HOTEL_ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."ROOM"."PRICE" IS 'Rooms price';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."ROOM"."ROOM_SIZE" IS 'Size of room';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."ROOM"."ROOM_ID" IS 'ID number of room';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RIADORA"."ROOM"."HOTEL_ID" IS 'ID number of hotel';
   COMMENT ON TABLE "RIADORA"."ROOM"  IS 'Rooms data';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Joining the two:

```
select hotel_id,
       count(*) as NumberOfRooms,
       count(distinct client_id) as NumberOfClients
from room
join payment on room.room_id =  payment.room_id
group by hotel_id;
```